# Identifying file changes in StorageFolder

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to keep a database in sync with the Windows 8 music library and I'm yet to find an efficient solution for doing so. I know that .NET has a `FileSystemWatcher` that's not available to Windows 8 apps. Currently, my idea is to compare the list of files returned by `GetFilesAsync` against my database and check if something was modified, deleted or added. I know this is not ideal but I can't find any other useful thing in `Windows.Storage`. My problem is that I want to make these updates automatically once there is a modification to the music library. Checking the `ModifiedDate` of the folders is useless when the changes happen in subfolders. Does anybody know if there is a way to tell when has a `StorageFolder` been modified?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get `ContentsChanged` to fire reliably, then the code below may help you determine what changed.

Note, it isn't fast. `GetBasicPropertiesAsync` appears to take ~5ms/file... so ~10 seconds to diff a set of 1000 files.

(I cannot get `ContentsChanged` to fire reliably, and, after hours of googling, it appears many others have the same problem)

```
    private class DiffSet
    {
        public IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> Added { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> Deleted { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> Changed { get; set; }
    }

    private static async Task<DiffSet> Diff(IEnumerable<StorageFile> oldSet, IEnumerable<StorageFile> newSet)
    {
        var newAsDict = newSet.ToDictionary(sf => sf.Path);

        var added = new List<StorageFile>();
        var deleted = new List<StorageFile>();
        var changed = new List<StorageFile>();

        var fromOldSet = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var oldFile in oldSet)
        {
            if (!newAsDict.ContainsKey(oldFile.Path))
            {
                deleted.Add(oldFile);
                continue;
            }

            var oldBasicProperties = await oldFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
            var newBasicProperties = await newAsDict[oldFile.Path].GetBasicPropertiesAsync();

            var oldDateModified = oldBasicProperties.DateModified;
            var newDateModified = newBasicProperties.DateModified;

            if (oldDateModified != newDateModified)
            {
                changed.Add(oldFile);
            }

            fromOldSet.Add(oldFile.Path);
        }

        foreach (var newFile in newSet)
        {
            if (!fromOldSet.Contains(newFile.Path))
                added.Add(newFile);
        }

        return new DiffSet
        {
            Added = added,
            Deleted = deleted,
            Changed = changed
        };
    }
```

Comment: Tristan, I know this is an old post, but did you ever figure out how to make `ContentsChanged` fire reliably?

Comment: I wish. I ended up writing a SQLite backed read-through cache to maintain knowledge of the file system, including a piece that, at low priority, double checks all known files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get that info from your Windows 8 app. Your best bet is to query the folders and files asynchronously and compare the info to that stored in the database. See one example of enumerating folders and files [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Folder-enumeration-sample-33ebd000). I know this is not very efficient for what you are trying to do. If you find any other better ways, please share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`StorageFileQueryResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.search.storagefilequeryresult.aspx) and its `ContentsChanged` event to be notified on changes on a folder and its subfolders. However the event does not contain any information about what actually changed, so you need to re-parse the folder and check if anything you're interested in has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    public async void ListenAsync() {
        query = storageFolder.CreateFileQuery();
        query.ContentsChanged += query_ContentsChanged;
        var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
    }

    void query_ContentsChanged(IStorageQueryResultBase sender, object args) {
        // args has no info about what changed. check manually
    }
```